# How to close Kafka ProducerConfig values

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

```
2018-03-22 11:50:29.175  INFO 12071 --- [io-26681-exec-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.ProducerConfig    : ProducerConfig values:
acks = 1
batch.size = 16384
bootstrap.servers = [ns014:9092]
buffer.memory = 33554432
client.id =
compression.type = none
```

Kafka in Spring Boot2.0，When I send message the picture value always appear.How can I close it?

I haven't found any changes to the configuration.

Comment: Don't post screenshots. Add it directly to your question.

Comment: Thanks，I'll change it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using KafkaProducer for configuring Kafka, You can close the channel as below :

```
Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
  producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("my-topic", 
  Integer.toString("any Data"), Integer.toString(i)));

  producer.close();
```

If you are using KafkaTemplate of async calls, You can do it as :

```
     ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, Payload>> sr = kafkaTemplate.send(topic, payload);
    kafkaTemplate.flush();
```

This will flush all settings for particular Kafka Producer.